# Golang Символы массив

Tags: массивы, golang

Как в Golang разделить строку на символы?

```
CurrentString := "Hello world"
```

в итоге должен быть массив и в нем

```
["H" "e" "l" "l" "o" " " "w" "o" "r" "l" "d"]
```

Answer (score 1):

используйте [strings.Split](https://pkg.go.dev/strings#Split) функцию для дробления строк

```
CurrentString := "Hello world"
array := strings.Split(CurrentString, "")
fmt.Printf("%#v", array)
```

> []string{"H", "e", "l", "l", "o", " ", "w", "o", "r", "l", "d"}